# set validation group to embedded forms in symfony 2

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, symfony-forms, symfony-2.3

how to set validation group in embedded forms ?
I have two entities A and B and form for each entities (FormA, FormB)
I am embedding form FormA in FormB

```
class FormB extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder->add('A', new FormA());
    }
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Acme\TestBundle\Entity\B',
            'validation_groups'=>function(FormInterface $form) {
                // set validation group for FormA here
             },
            'cascade_validation'=>true
        ));
    }
}
```

How do I set validation group of FormA from FormB?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It works for me

```
class FormB extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder->add('A', new FormA(), array('validation_groups' => array('yourValidationGroup')));
    }
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Acme\TestBundle\Entity\B',
            'cascade_validation'=>true
        ));
    }
}
```

Also defining the validation group in FormB->setDefaultOptions work. It apply the validation group to all subforms.

```
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Acme\TestBundle\Entity\B',
            'cascade_validation'=>true,
            'validation_groups' => array('yourValidationGroup')
        ));
    }
```

To use that depending on underlying data you can put that code on a event listener:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA,
            function(FormEvent $event) {
                $form=$event->getForm();
                /**
                 * @var ContactDetail $detail
                 */
                $entity=$form->getData();
                if($entity->getA()->isRequired()){
                    $form->add('A', new FormA(), array('validation_groups' => array('yourValidationGroup')));
                } else {
                    $form->add('A', new FormA(), array());
                }
            }
    );
}
```

Comment: i m looking to do this in closure for validation groups since i need to add validation group depending on some form element value

Comment: I add an example that adds a group validation depending on underlying data with EventListeners.

Comment: im trying `$builder->add('A', new FormA(), array('validation_groups' => array('yourValidationGroup')));` and didn't works for me... but putting validation_groups into default options works... Do yo know why first attempt doesnt works?

Answer (score 2):

The property `cascade_validation` is [deprecated in Symfony 2.8](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/reference/forms/types/form.html#cascade-validation), and will be removed in Symfony 3.0. For use `cascade_validation`, you should use [`@Assert\Valid` constraint](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/reference/constraints/Valid.html).

```
class Profile
{
  /**
   * @var Address
   * 
   * @Assert\Valid()
   */
  private $address;
}
```

P.S. Attention: links provides for Symfony 2.8 version.